# add_filter for specific pages

Tags: filters, the-content

Is it possible to add this filter

`add_filter("the_content", "magicalender_get_event_page");`

But only for one specific page, for example

`if($post->post_name == "magicalenderpage")`

If I put the if statement inside the function, then on any other pages the content isn't displayed - and with an else statement afterwards that echoes out the content of the page otherwise I encounter problems where it interferes with other plug-ins that also do things with

`add_filter("the_content", "foo");`

The magicalender_get_event_page function is as follows

```
function magicalender_get_event_page(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;

    if($post->post_name == "magicalenderpage"){
        echo "<div class=\"magi_calender\">";
        for($i = 0; $event = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."magicalender", ARRAY_A, $i); $i++){
            echo"
                <div class=\"event\">
                    <h1>".$event['event']."</h1>
                    <h2>".date('m/d/Y', strtotime($event['dmy']))."</h2>
                    <div>".str_replace("&amp;", "&", str_replace("&#39;", "'", str_replace("&#34;", "\"", $event['desc'])))."</div>
                </div>
            ";
        }
        echo "</div>";

        $o = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."magioptions", ARRAY_A);
        echo"
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                var priority = '".$o['dm']."';
                var customDays = new Array('".$o['monday']."', '".$o['tuesday']."', '".$o['wednesday']."', '".$o['thursday']."', '".$o['friday']."', '".$o['saturday']."', '".$o['sunday']."');
                var customMonths = new Array('".$o['january']."', '".$o['february']."', '".$o['march']."', '".$o['april']."', '".$o['may']."', '".$o['june']."', '".$o['july']."', '".$o['august']."', '".$o['september']."', '".$o['october']."', '".$o['november']."', '".$o['december']."');
                var customMonthsShort = new Array('".$o['jan']."', '".$o['feb']."', '".$o['mar']."', '".$o['apr']."', '".$o['ma']."', '".$o['jun']."', '".$o['jul']."', '".$o['aug']."', '".$o['sep']."', '".$o['oct']."', '".$o['nov']."', '".$o['dec']."');
                jQuery(\".magi_calender\").magiCalender(priority, customDays, customMonths, customMonthsShort);
            </script>
        ";
    }
    else{
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is helpful to post your entire filter and callback code, rather than just pieces.

But, I suspect that the problem is that you're not **returning `$the_content`** outside of your conditional, e.g.:

```
function magicalendar_get_event_page( $content ) {
    if ( $post->post_name == 'magicalendarpage' ) {
        // Do something to $content
        return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'magicalendar_get_event_page' );
```

If that's the case, move the return *outside* the conditional:

```
function magicalendar_get_event_page( $content ) {
    if ( $post->post_name == 'magicalendarpage' ) {
        // Do something to $content
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'magicalendar_get_event_page' );
```

To know why/how it's interfering with other filters on `'the_content'`, we probably need to see your code.

**EDIT**

At least two problems:

1. You're not passing `$content` as an argument to your filter callback
2. **DO NOT ECHO FILTER OUTPUT!** Return it. That is very likely causing your problem with other filters applied to `the_content`.

If you need to filter `the_content` specifically before or after other filters, then add a priority to your `add_filter()` call. 10 is the default. Use a lower number to filter *sooner*; use a higher number to filter *later*.

Comment: Actually I basically have what you have there, but the problem is some plug-ins that do similar things to mine (whereas the $content is replaced with something else, and not actually shown) then the two plug-ins clash. I've updated my post to include all of my function.

Comment: @Stephen Cook - your code certainly does not have `$content` as the function argument - see in @Chip Bennett's answer `function magicalendar_get_event_page( $content ) {` - also, why don't you consider to create a page template for this page?

Comment: A Page Template is quite possibly the way to go here. P.S. see edited answer.

Comment: I actually did have $content as a parameter in my plug-in, I don't know how I found a copy to paste here without it. But thanks, I'll try using "return" not "echo" and also a page template

Comment: I'd probably go with a custom Page template. If you go that route, you don't even have to call `the_content()` (just put your custom code in place of the Loop). That way, you don't even have to worry about other Plugins filtering `the_content`.

Comment: actually, need to put $post to global.